# Is it be possible to migrate /replicate certian Tables from on-premi SQL to BigQuery or Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I need your suggestions on the following Scenario:

***USE CASE***

I have an on-premises MySQL-Database (20 Tables) and I need to transfer/sync certain Tables(6 Tables) from this Database to BigQuery for Reporting.

**Solution:**

1- Transfer the whole Database to Cloud SQL using [Database Migration Service DMS](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/mysql) and then connect the Cloud-SQL instance with BigQuery and query the needed Tables for reporting.

2- Use Dataflow pipeline with pub/sub : [How do I move data from MySQL to BigQuery?](http://How%20do%20I%20move%20data%20from%20MySQL%20to%20BigQuery?)

Any suggestion How to Syn some Tables to BigQuery without migrating the Whole Database?

Big Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to synchronize (like daily) your on-prem MySQL databases to BigQuery, or do you just want to migrate once from on-prem MySQL to BQ ?

Comment: I want first to migrate the Tables once and then set a daily sync-job.

Comment: For the first init, have you considered exporting the MySQL tables to CSV files, uploading them to Google Cloud Storage, and finally importing them to BQ with `bq load` ? To me, it's the easiest solution. For the sync job, you may need to set up a cronjob doing the same thing daily automatically. Does that help ?

Comment: 'exporting the MySQL tables to CSV files' I am now on this process but it's a little overwhelming since Data Size for every Table >> 1 GB. I thought there is an automated way that i could connect my on-prem MySQL within GCP and upload them to GCS then to BQ.   for Sync i would like to stay away from Cronjob the I looking for a Change-based-sync job or  CDC. Thanks For your Suggestion, @norbjd !  .

Comment: Is it possible to sync all the table?

Comment: I have reason to believe that opting for CloudSQL over BQ might allow you to utilize the methods described in the [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations) to then dump the daily sync into a CloudSQL using [this method](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#mysqldump).